# validation_data` should be a tuple `(val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight)` Keras CNN

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I have 123 mri images in nii format for training.
I also have 30 mri images in nii format for testing.
The images are 3D.
The are stored as it is below:

```
 train/A    73 nii files inside A
 train/B    50 nii files inside B
 test/A     18 nii files inside A
 test/B     12 nii files inside B
```

I want to classify the images into A and B.
I use Python and keras.
The code is:

```
from google.colab import drive
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv3D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling3D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
drive.mount('/content/drive')
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), input_shape = (110, 110, 110, 1), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size = (2, 2, 2)))
classifier.add(Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size = (2, 2, 2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
train_data_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/DTI_test/DATA/AD/train/'
test_data_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/DTI_test/DATA/AD/test/'
nb_train_samples =123 
nb_test_samples = 30
epochs = 10
batch_size = 5
classifier.fit_generator(train_data_dir,
steps_per_epoch = nb_train_samples,
epochs = epochs,
validation_data = test_data_dir,
validation_steps = nb_test_samples)
```

When I run the model, I got the error below.

```
ValueError: `validation_data` should be a tuple `(val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight)` or `(val_x, val_y)`. Found: /content/drive/My Drive/DTI_test/DATA/AD/test/
```

Any idea what is the error about?
Thanks in advance

Comment: To use fit_generator you need to instance valid generators, a string pointing to your dataset is not a valid generator

Comment: Thanks so much. But I did not get your point. is it possible to clarify more or a link to explain it? Regards

Comment: There are examples here: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#ImageDataGenerator , also note that ImageDataGenerator does not support nii format, you need to convert to JPG or PNG, or use a custom generator that can load such images. I am curious, where did you get your code from?

Comment: I was reading about CNN and Keras. So I wrote if from the sources I read.